# Segnet in Keras: total size of new array must be unchanged error

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am implementing Segnet in Python. Following is the code.

```
img_w = 480
img_h = 360
pool_size = 2

def build_model(img_w, img_h, pool_size):
    n_labels = 12

    kernel = 3

    encoding_layers = [
        Conv2D(64, (kernel, kernel), input_shape=(img_h, img_w, 3), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(64, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool_size,pool_size)),

        Convolution2D(128, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(128, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool_size,pool_size)),

        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool_size,pool_size)),

        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool_size,pool_size)),

        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (pool_size,pool_size)),
    ]

    autoencoder = models.Sequential()
    autoencoder.encoding_layers = encoding_layers

    for l in autoencoder.encoding_layers:
        autoencoder.add(l)

    decoding_layers = [
        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),

        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(512, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),

        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(256, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(128, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),

        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(128, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(64, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),

        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(64, (kernel, kernel), padding='same'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Activation('relu'),
        Convolution2D(n_labels, (1, 1), padding='valid', activation="sigmoid"),
        BatchNormalization(),
    ]
    autoencoder.decoding_layers = decoding_layers
    for l in autoencoder.decoding_layers:
        autoencoder.add(l)

    autoencoder.add(Reshape((n_labels, img_h * img_w)))
    autoencoder.add(Permute((2, 1)))
    autoencoder.add(Activation('softmax'))



    return autoencoder

model = build_model(img_w, img_h, pool_size)
```

But it returns me error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-051f06a53a14> in <module>()
----> 1 model = build_model(img_w, img_h, pool_size)

<ipython-input-20-c37fd94c8641> in build_model(img_w, img_h, pool_size)
    119         autoencoder.add(l)
    120 
--> 121     autoencoder.add(Reshape((n_labels, img_h * img_w)))
    122     autoencoder.add(Permute((2, 1)))
    123     autoencoder.add(Activation('softmax'))
    ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I can't see any reason for the error. When I change img_w and img_h to 256, this error is resolved but problem is that's not the image size or original dataset so I can't use that. How to resolve this?

Comment: Please include the complete error stack trace, from the code it is not obvious which part is producing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are performing `(2, 2)` downsampling 5 times so, let's track the shape:

```
(360, 480) -> (180, 240) -> (90, 120) -> (45, 60) -> (22, 30) -> (11, 15)
```

And now upsampling:

```
(11, 15) -> (22, 30) -> (44, 60) -> (88, 120) -> (176, 240) -> (352, 480)
```

So, when you try to `reshape` the output using original shape - the problem is raised due to model mismatch.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Resize your image that both input dimensions are divisible by `32` (e.g. `(352, 480)` or `(384, 480)`.
2. Add `ZeroPadding2D(((1, 0), (0, 0)))` after 3rd upsampling to change the shape from `(44, 60)` to `(45, 60)`, what will make your network finish with a good output shape.

**Other issues:**

Please find out that the last `MaxPooling2D` is followed by the first `Upsampling2D`. This might be a problem as this is an useless bottlenecking of your network.

Comment: You were right on target. That was the exact problem. Just one line wasted my whole day!

Comment: So I'm happy that I could help you :)