# Keras Conv2D decoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am dealing with images of different size (x,y). When using `UpSampling2D` after `MaxPooling2D` it doesn't reconstruct it well since x-dim is not equal to y-dim. It works when x=y (e.g. 28x28), but in my case (388x45). How can I solve this problem.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(388, 45, 1))  

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to add `ZeroPadding2D` after the upsampling layer to arrive to the desired shape.

Practically, if you have the shape of your image ((19,30)), in order to get to an even number, say, on the first position, you would add:

```
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x) #say here the shape is (19,30) after upsampling but you need (20,30)
x = ZeroPadding2D(((1, 0), (0, 0)))(x) # change to ZeroPadding2D(((0, 0), (0, 1))) if you want second dimension to increase by 1
```

You can find a perfect usage of ZeroPadding2D in this answer: 
[segnet in keras: total size of new array must be unchanged error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610981/segnet-in-keras-total-size-of-new-array-must-be-unchanged-error)